# How to store an Alarm in SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, sdk, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager, alarm

I have an app, which has an Alarm (I am using `ELAPSED REALTIME`)
And the alarm starts when the switcher is on. I want to cancel the alarm, when I close the application and restart it. But it isn't working. I think I need to save the state of the alarm in SharedPreferences. Is that possible? If yes how? Is this useful? 
I know how to save the state of the `switch` using SharedPreferences
If you need anything, like code or somethin, please let me know

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Store alarm? Not possible. Store required value into prefs which will be used to create Alarm.

Comment: So, how can I cancel then the alarm?

Comment: That need ID. See there are too many examples to cancel

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert alarm's calendar into milliseconds and save it in the alarm object.
2. Save the pendingIntent's ID in the alarm object.
3. Convert the alarm object's arraylist into json using GSON and store the json in the SharedPreferences.

To save the state you can save a boolean for isAlarmEnabled in the object, and get alarm details from sharedprefs using the same way.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a code-oriented community so yes please, do share your code here.  Also read the help section on answering: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering